# Prove that $m\mid a$ if and only if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that $m\mid a$ if and only if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$.

This is what I have thus far:

Proof: Let $a$ be in the set of integers such that $a=0+km$, where $k$ is an integer. Then by the definition of divides, $m\mid a$. Since $m\mid a$, by the definition of congruency $a\equiv 0 \pmod{m}$.

I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: What's your definition for congruences? It seems to me that there is literally nothing to prove.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}
m\mid a &\iff a=nm \text{ for some }n\in \Bbb Z \\
&\iff a-0=nm\text{ for some } n\in\Bbb Z \\
&\iff m\mid (a-0) \\
&\iff a\equiv 0\pmod{m}.
\end{align}$$